# Dynamic django models, json

Tags: json, django-models, django-serializer

Please tell me how the django model should look like if I have a view of how the data in JSON format is obtained:

```
  values {
  "firstname": "l",
  "lastname": "m",
  "links": [
     {
       "linkname": "https://www.youtube.com/",
       "linkurl": "https://www.youtube.com/"
     },
     {
       "linkname": "https://www.youtube.com/",
       "linkurl": "https://www.youtube.com/"
     }
  ]
  }
```

That is, as you can see from the example, there can be as many such Links as you like (this is a dynamic nested form).

This is how it means (as shown below) I send it all to the server (rest framework api):

```
onSubmit={async (values, actions) => {
             await axios ({
             method: 'post',
             url: 'http://localhost:8000/something/',
             data: JSON.stringify(values, null, 2);
           })
        }}
```

Can you tell me how to organize it on the server in django models and serializer so that everything is stored correctly in the database.

Thank you in advance who will help

I tried to present models in django like this:

**Models.py:**

```
class WorkSuper(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField("First name", max_length=10, blank="True")
    lastname = models.CharField("Last name", max_length=30, blank="True")
    linkname = models.CharField("link name", max_length=100, blank="True")
    linkurl = models.CharField("link url", max_length=100, blank="True")
```

**Serializers.py:**

```
class WorkSuperSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = WorkSuper
        fields = [
            'id', 
            'firstname',
            'lastname',
            'linkname',
            'linkurl'
        ]
```

And expected that everything would work, but only empty lines and not all Links come to the database

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zyX4.jpg)